# How to how to approximate lines (change the y-axis) to improve comparison

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having problem to plot two lines in ggplot2, since I need they be closer to improve the comparison. I'm tried to change the y-scale using 'log' and 'sqrt', but the lines are still far apart.

My data is big, I can't upload here, but here is my code

```
ggplot(data_sex, aes(x = year, y = sqrt(log(ratemort)), color = sex)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = sex)) +
  coord_cartesian( ylim = c(3.25,3.67))+
  geom_point()
```

[image: img]

where year 'sex' is a factor and 'ratemort' is a number.

I expect to approximate the lines to improve the visualization.

Comment: Try changing the y limits to 2-5 or something bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about change only the visualization way? You can use `facet_wrap()` with free scales:

```
# some fake data: it's not necessary your data you can't post them
# but a kind-of-your-data is always welcome
data_sex <- data.frame(year = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005),
                       ratemort = c(1,2,1,2,1,3,100,200,200,300,200,500),
                       sex = c('0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1','1'))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data_sex, aes(x = year, y =(ratemort))) +
  geom_line(aes(group = sex)) +
  geom_point() +facet_wrap(vars(sex), scales = 'free', ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Or if you're interested in make the lines more "near", you can make them as percentage: it's clear that it's not the real values plotted, so you've specify the different magnitude of the values, that is lost here:

```
library(dplyr)
data_sex %>%
  group_by( sex, year) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(ratemort)) %>%
  mutate(perc = n / sum(n)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = year, y =perc, color = sex)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = sex)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: About your second approach, how can I interpret? In 2003, e.g. 20% of the deaths are from women and 20% from men?

Comment: The interpretation is that the deaths in 2000 for woman are the 10% on the total  from 2000 to 2005, in 2005 the 30%. If it makes sense to you: this is a simple way to have the lines near.